# Count of rows from all views in Oracle with a condition

Tags: oracle, dbms-xmlgen

I am trying to get count of all rows from views in oracle schema and my code is working fine. But when i try to add a condition like where actv_ind = 'Y', i am unable to get it working. Any suggestions on how to modify the code to make it working?

```html
SELECT view_name,
TO_NUMBER(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) cnt from '||owner||'.'||view_name||
'where'||view_name||'.'||'actv_ind= Y')),'/ROWSET/ROW/CNT')) as VIEW_CNT
FROM all_views
WHERE owner = 'ABC'  AND view_name not in ('LINK$')
```

I am getting the error ACTV_IND : Invalid Identifier.

Comment: ACTV_IND is not a valid field in all_views

Comment: I need to get the record count from all the views where actv_ind = Y. The above is bringing all the records. How can i filter based in actv_ind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages from DBMS_XMLGEN are not very helpful so you need to be very careful with the syntax of the SQL statement. Add a space before and after the `where`, and add quotation marks around the `Y`:

```
SELECT view_name,
TO_NUMBER(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) cnt from '||owner||'.'||view_name||
' where '||view_name||'.'||'actv_ind= ''Y''')),'/ROWSET/ROW/CNT')) as VIEW_CNT
FROM all_views
WHERE owner = 'ABC'  AND view_name not in ('LINK$');
```

The query still assumes that every view contains the column ACTV_IND. If that is not true, you might want to base the query off of `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'ACTV_IND'`.

Here's a simple sample schema I used for testing:

```
create user abc identified by abc;
create or replace view abc.view1 as select 1 id, 'Y' actv_ind from dual;
create or replace view abc.view2 as select 2 id, 'N' actv_ind from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I modified the query to include all tab columns and it worked in Oracle. But when i am executing from a third party application its throwing a new error with invalid number. Not able to figure out why its throwing that error?.Any pointers? SELECT table_name,
TO_NUMBER(extractvalue(xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) cnt from '||owner||'.'||table_name||
' where '||table_name||'.'||'actv_ind= ''Y''')),'/ROWSET/ROW/CNT')) VIEW_CNT
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE owner = 'ABC' and column_name='ACTV_IND' AND table_name not in ('LINK$');

Comment: @Arun.K That error implies that some of the ACTV_IND columns are not strings. You may need to filter out non-string values with a condition like this: `and data_type in ('VARCHAR2', 'VARCHAR', 'CHAR', 'CLOB', 'NVARCHAR2', 'NVARCHAR', 'NCHAR', 'NCLOB'); `. You may need to create a separate SQL statement to handle numeric ACTV_IND, and then `UNION ALL` the two queries. Or you could have `case when data_type = ...` logic that builds the right predicate for each data type.